# How to auto assign dates to buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have a form that has 90 buttons on it, one button for each day.  When a user first signs into the program, they enter their user name and a date.  I want to take the date the user entered and auto fill the text fields of each button.  For example the text for btnDay1 would be 18 Mar, btnDay2 would be 19 Mar, etc., etc.

Someone suggested using this code:

```
DateTime time = dateTimepicker1.Value; //this is user selected date, you can use your own way
foreach(Button b in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    if(b.Name != "button1" || b.Name != "button2")
    {
         b.Text = time.Date.ToString("dd MMM");
         time = time.Date.AddDays(1); //setting for next button        
    }
}
```

but the compiler tells me that dateTimepicker1 doesn't exist in its current content.  I have never used dateTimepicker and it's not in my textbook so I am unfamiliar with how to use it.  I looked at the MSDN library but the example there is so completely different than DateTime time = dateTimepicker1.Value that all it does is leave me more confused than I was before.

Comment: So how do you let the user select a date? Do you have a DateTime already by the time you reach this snippet?

Comment: what control you placed to select date? does it have the ID dateTimepicker1 ?

Comment: I have a textbox called txtStartDate.  So I need to instantiate a DateTime object and assign that object to my text box?

Comment: if you change the textbox to a DateTimePicker, and name it `dateTimepicker1`, the code you have should work. However, I'm not sure you need the `if` statement there.  Do you have two buttons called `button1` and `button2` that you don't want changed?

Comment: whoever edited this and added homework, this is not homework.  I know of no homework assignment that has you working with a form with 90 buttons on it.  This is a workout project I am trying to create outside of my programming class. If it were homework I would have said as much.

Comment: @ vlad.  I see what you are saying.  OK.  Yes, I have several buttons that are not part of the 90 day buttons.  Thank you very much.  I figured I was missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a textbox to get the inputs from the user then

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.Text); 
    foreach(Button b in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
    {
        if(b.Name != "button1" || b.Name != "button2")
        {
             b.Text = time.Date.ToString("dd MMM");
             time = time.Date.AddDays(1); //setting for next button        
        }
    }
```

It expects that you have two buttons button1 and button2 that need to be avoided.

To make interface better,  you can put a date picker instead of the textbox and change its name to `dateTimepicker1` and use your code in the question.